# Add Subject Encoding in Postfix

Tags: postfix

### How can I use postfix to encode subjects with special characters?

I am using a proprietary software which does not encode the e-mail subject header. If the header contains a special character (for example german umlaut: öäüß) it causes problems on the receiver side.

The software runs on Linux and uses to local postfix daemon to send the e-mails. Can I somehow add the encoding in postfix?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to (regex-)replace a fixed number of possible header values, `header_checks` will suffice.

If you need to convert arbitrary headers values to RFC2047, you will want an additional script, which can be plugged into postfix using interfaces such as *milter* or *filter*. Bindings are available for all popular languages, calling the actual header replacement will likely take less time than setting it all up.

<sub>The simple case - converting an SMTPUTF8-received *valid* mail into a non-SMTPUTF8 deliverable *still valid* mail has may or may not at one point become a postfix feature (see `WISHLIST` in postfix tarball).</sub>